# repair corrupt acl

Tags: windows-vista, acl

My friend is running windows vista and it's not working any more.  I've run diagnostics and found that three files in the C:\Windows\System32 folder have corrupt ACLs. System repair fails because windows can't access the files to overwrite or repair those files.

I suspect that her antivirus program accidentally quarantined them.

Now the computer cannot boot because it cannot read these files.

I have access to startup recovery tools, a vista disk, and command prompt.  Is there a way I can manually or automatically repair or replace the damaged files?

As I said before, Windows Repair has thus far proved inadequate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try running chkdisk /r just in case it's a file system error that's causing the problem. If not then I think your going to need to find a way to move them out of the way so you can replace them with a good copy.  Depending on the files you might be able to do that from safe mode, otherwise you'll need a bootable CD (bartpe or ubuntu live cd would be easiest). Once they are out of the way your system repair will probably have a better chance.

Comment: The problem is I can't access them because of the bad ACL.  Thus I can't copy, move, or delete them because it cannot determine my permissions.  I can access the attributes and other metadata just fine and ran a disk check with no errors found.  The only thing I can't access is the ACL and because of that-the file.

Comment: That's why I expect you'll have to use a bootable CD since it won't care about the ACL.